org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.TestSuiteExecutionException: Could not complete execution for Gradle
During the spring boot upgrade 3.4.0 i am getting below error which is actually working fine with 3.3.6.
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.TestSuiteExecutionException: Could not complete execution for Gradle Test Executor 20.
   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:64)
   at java.base@17.0.11/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at java.base@17.0.11/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
   at java.base@17.0.11/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   at java.base@17.0.11/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
   at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
   at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
   at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
   at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
   at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy5.stop(Unknown Source)
   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$3.run(TestWorker.java:193)
   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
   at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
   at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:113)
   at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:65)
   at app//worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
   at app//worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74) Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/platform/launcher/TestExecutionListener
   at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
   at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1012)
   at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
   at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:862)
   at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:760)
   at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:681)
   at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:639)
   at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
   at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
   at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
   at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467)
   at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.nextProviderClass(ServiceLoader.java:1217)
   at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNextService(ServiceLoader.java:1228)
   at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1273)
   at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$2.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1309)
   at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1393)
   at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:132)
   at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1845)
   at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
   at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
   at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
   at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
   at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
   at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:596)
   at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.LauncherFactory.registerTestExecutionListeners(LauncherFactory.java:179)
   at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.LauncherFactory.createDefaultLauncher(LauncherFactory.java:137)
   at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.LauncherFactory.create(LauncherFactory.java:125)
   at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.LauncherFactory.create(LauncherFactory.java:109)
   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:97)
   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:79)
   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:75)
   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:62)
   ... 18 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.platform.launcher.TestExecutionListener
   at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
   at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
   at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
   ... 50 more

pls find the dependencies details below
   dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.3.6")
        classpath 'org.owasp:dependency-check-gradle:8.2.1'
    }    //Testing
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter")
}

when upgradeing the spring boot version to 3.4.0 in parent build.gradle file the test cases were not able to run for one of the dependent service, how to sort out this issue.

I encountered this and created a bare bones Spring Boot 3.4 project using Spring Initializer for version 3.4 Java 17 and noticed that it included this test runtime dependency:
testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher'

I included this in my project and it was then able to locate the missing class and my tests started executing

I am seeing the same issue as OP when moving from Spring Boot 3.3.6 to Spring Boot 3.4.0. Adding this extra runtime dependency does allow my tests to run, but I dont know why the new dependency is necessary. Looking through the dependency output I dont see junit-platform-launcher in my old dependencies for Spring Boot 3.3 and I dont see any notes from the Spring team in either the 3.4 Release Notes, or the Spring Framework 6.2 release notes. I hate to add another dependency without knowing why
